# How do I find out if an oracle database is set to autocommit?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

And while we're at it, how do I switch between autocommit and non-autocommit?

Comment: As far as I know there is no autocommit on the server side. Only on the client side.

Comment: It seems the OP's concern was  "How to find out whether my session with the oracle database has autocommit on".  Half of the answer is "it is not on the DB, it is on the client".  The second half is to answer how to check/change it on the various clients.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) 4

- **Window** > **Preferences** > **Database** > **Advanced** > check/uncheck **Autocommit**

### [Oracle SQL*Plus](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/toc.htm)

- Use [`SET AUTOCOMMIT`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG063)

### [SQuirreL SQL Client](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) Version 3.7

- **File** > **New Session Properties** > **SQL** tab > SQL section > check/uncheck **Auto Commit SQL**

### [Toad for Oracle](http://software.dell.com/products/toad-for-oracle/) Xpert 9.6.1.1

- **View** > **Toad Options...** > **Oracle** > **Transactions** > check/uncheck **Commit after every statement**

### [SQL Workbench/J](http://sql-workbench.net/)

- Check the "Autocommit" property in the connection profile to set the connection default
- Use **SQL > Autocommit** from the menu to change it dynamically
- Use `SET AUTOCOMMIT`

Comment: There are probably hundreds of different tools that have an autocommit settings.  Listing them here won't be helpful.

Comment: True but only 3 are widely used and SQL Developer is one of them

Comment: I'll convert this answer to a community wiki, so that everybody can contribute. It would be nice to have a list with many tools in this post.

Answer (score 19):

**There is no such thing as autocommit in Oracle** (server). Some **client** applications however default to autocommit (meaning they deliberately issue a commit between each statement). You will have to read the documentation of your application in order to determine if this is the case.

Comment: Thanks. Found it:

sql*plus:
    SQL> show autocommit;
    autocommit OFF
    SQL> set autocommit ON;

sqlpython does not seem to have this feature.

Comment: @0x89: SQL*Plus is only a CLIENT application, it is NOT the Oracle DB :)

Comment: Yes, I got that after reading your answer. So I added the information how to set sql*plus to autocommit, so that people who basically just want to know how to switch sql*plus to autocommit can read it here.

Comment: This answer is already outdated. Now Oracle supports autocommit !

Comment: @tnkh: I'm not aware of an autocommit server setting. You can set your client to autocommit if you so desire, but the database has no such settings as far as I know. See for example [this article by askTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:314816776423). Admittedly, it was in 2012, things may have changed since. Please let us know if you find any indication that the database now supports autocommit.

Answer (score 5):

Try command `show autocommit` from command prompt. Steps:

- Open `SQL*PLUS` from command prompt in admin mode
- Type command `show autocommit`