# How to enable autocommit in oracle permanently?

Tags: database, oracle

I can enable auto-commit in sqlplus but, that will be enabled for one session only. I want auto-commit to be enabled for all the sessions of oracle - all sqlplus sessions and all applications using oracle db.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366851/how-do-i-find-out-if-an-oracle-database-is-set-to-autocommit#1366898

Comment: You want a bad, bad thing.  For SQL\*Plus, you can edit (or create) file  `$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql`.  Any SQL\*Plus sessions launched from that machine will run those commands (e.g. `SET AUTOCOMMIT ON`).  There is, thankfully, no way to do it at the database level to affect every user and every application from every client machine.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak - experience with humans in general (in all fields of activity, not just in technology) suggests that some (many?) people will not listen to others when they are told they want "a bad, bad thing". They have to hit their own head against the wall, sometimes repeatedly, until they understand **why**.

Comment: "*all applications using oracle db*" - that's not possible.